# Eclipse-maven project error when creating a new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using eclipse, m2eclipse plugin and maven to create a new maven project, following this procedure, 
http://o7planning.org/en/10101/install-maven-into-eclipse

However, when a new maven project is created, no JRE system library, no Maven libraries. only src, target and pom.xml like below. is this normal? if not, how can I avoid it? Thanks!

maven version: 3.3.9
eclipse: neon 4..6.0

[Click for the picture of the maven project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5amQC.png)

Comment: Please share the error displayed when pom.xml is opened

Answer (score 0):

right click the project -> Maven -> Update Project